# How to accomplish this in python?

Tags: python

Given the following input file:

```
a = 2
b = 3
c = a * b
d = c + 4
```

I want to run the above input file through a python program that produces
the following output:

```
a = 2
b = 3
c = a * b = 6
d = c + 4 = 10
```

The input file is a legal python program, but the output is python with
extra output that prints the value of each variable to the right of the
declaration/assignment. Alternatively, the output could look like:

```
a = 2
b = 3
c = a * b
c = 6
d = c + 4
d = 10
```

The motivation for this is to implement a simple "engineer's notebook"
that allows chains of calculations without needing print statements
in the source file.

Here's what I have after modifying D.Shawley's (much appreciated) contribution:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from math import *

import sys
locals = dict()

for line in sys.stdin:
  line = line.strip()
  if line == '':
    continue
  saved = locals.copy()
  stmt = compile(line,'<stdin>','single')
  eval(stmt,None,locals)
  print line,
  for (k,v) in locals.iteritems():
    if k not in saved:
      print '=', v,
  print
```

Comment: please format your code using the built-in tools next time.

Comment: Also, can you try clarifying what sort of interface we are talking about?  Will the output be a text file?  Displayed on the screen?

Comment: Interface is: input from file or stdin, output to stdout. Running from linux command line. So far, I just have a python script with print statements that dump the variable names and contents. Want to create a program that "auto-prints" variable names and their values.

Comment: please edit your question adding this additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following is a good start.  It's not very Pythonic, but it is pretty close.  It doesn't distinguish between newly added variables and modified ones.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
locals = dict()
for line in sys.stdin:
    saved = locals.copy()
    stmt = compile(line, '<stdin>', 'single')
    eval(stmt, None, locals)
    print line.strip(),
    for (k,v) in locals.iteritems():
        if k not in saved:
            print '=', v,
    print
```

Comment: That certainly evaluates each expression line-by-line but does not meet (either of) the output requirements in the question ;-) That said, it should give @gregben enough Python to be able to complete his assignment.

Comment: I modified your code to skip blank lines. BTW, this is not an assignment. I was just looking for a simple replacement for mathcad that I could run in a terminal.

Comment: If you are looking for a quick calculator, you might want to try either [`bc`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/bc.html) or [`dc`](http://www.FreeBSD.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dc).  I end up using `dc` more than I would like to admit for those quick little calculations.

Comment: I've used bc and dc from before I can remember. Trying to create an extensive set of calcs with documentation. Trying 'smath studio' right now. Thanks again.